# What type of IProducerConsumerCollection<T> to use for my task?

Tags: c#

I have exactly 100 Sensors each "measuring" own data. I have exactly one *DataSender* which should send information from "sensors". The most recent information should be sent.

Bandwidth of the channel may be less than data produced by 100 sensors. In this case some data can be skipped - but we should be "roughly fair". For example, we could skip every second measurement from each sensor.

I don't know how often each sensor generates data, but in general they generate data pretty often.

After my other posts:

- [how to create singleton which always running in separate thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5801952/how-to-create-singleton-which-always-running-in-separate-thread)
- [Modified Producer/Consumer example, any problems with it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5842553/modified-producer-consumer-example-any-problems-with-it)

I have decided that I have classical **Producer/Consumer** problem, with:

- 100 Producers, and
- 1 Consumer

I've been suggested to use [`BlockingCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997371.aspx) for this. The only problem with `BlockingCollection` - once you have added item, you cannot **replace** it. But in my application, if sensor produces a new value, and previous value was not processed by the `Consumer`, the value should be **replaced**.

Should I use use a [`ConcurentDictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`ConcurentBag`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381779(v=vs.110).aspx) for that task?

Conceptually, **all I need** is an array of 100 elements.

Sensor #33 should **replace** it's value into array[33]:

```
| Sensor | Value |
|--------|-------|
|      1 |       |
|      2 |       |
|      3 |       |
/......../......./
|     32 |       |
|     33 | 101.9 |
|     34 |       |
/......../......./
|     98 |       |
|     99 |       |
|    100 |       |
```

`Consumer` should take value from `array[33]` and if not null, then send it and set array[33] to null. `Consumer` should react on any not null values in array asap.

Comment: When there are messages from different devices in the collection, which one should you send?

Comment: messages from all sensors should be sent. each sensor has equal priority. if bandwidth is not enough to sent all messages from all sensors, then some data can be skiped. for example we can sent every second/third/fourth measurement from each sensor

Comment: If you have to be fair to every sensor then why do the sensors need to say they have new data ready? The consumer could just poll each sensor in order, seeing if it has new data. If it does have new data it gets the latest and sends it, if its not new then it just skips it.

Comment: backend application is pretty critical to receive data asap (actually it's financical trading software). data should be sent asap. that' why sensor should notify when new data available.

Comment: @javapowered Comment is not consistent with problem statement. "DataSender which should send information from sensors"  Why would you want to deal with concurrency data with a separate store?

Comment: @Blam sorry this question is so old that I don't rememer it already

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should implement your own `IProducerConsumerCollection<T>`. That's why it's an interface: so that you could easily make your own.

You could do it using `Dictionary<K,V>` and `Queue<T>` to make sure receiving the data is fair, i.e. if you have just one device that produces data very fast, you won't send data just from this one.

```
public class DeviceDataQueue<TDevice, TData>
    : IProducerConsumerCollection<Tuple<TDevice, TData>>
{
    private readonly object m_lockObject = new object();
    private readonly Dictionary<TDevice, TData> m_data
        = new Dictionary<TDevice, TData>();
    private readonly Queue<TDevice> m_queue = new Queue<TDevice>();

    //some obviously implemented methods elided, just make sure they are thread-safe

    public int Count { get { return m_queue.Count; } }

    public object SyncRoot { get { return m_lockObject; } }

    public bool IsSynchronized { get { return true; } }

    public bool TryAdd(Tuple<TDevice, TData> item)
    {
        var device = item.Item1;
        var data = item.Item2;

        lock (m_lockObject)
        {
            if (!m_data.ContainsKey(device))
                m_queue.Enqueue(device);

            m_data[device] = data;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public bool TryTake(out Tuple<TDevice, TData> item)
    {
        lock (m_lockObject)
        {
            if (m_queue.Count == 0)
            {
                item = null;
                return false;
            }

            var device = m_queue.Dequeue();
            var data = m_data[device];
            m_data.Remove(device);
            item = Tuple.Create(device, data);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

When used along these lines:

```
Queue = new BlockingCollection<Tuple<IDevice, Data>>(
    new DeviceDataQueue<IDevice, Data>());

Device1 = new Device(1, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3), Queue);
Device2 = new Device(2, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), Queue);

while (true)
{
    var tuple = Queue.Take();
    var device = tuple.Item1;
    var data = tuple.Item2;

    Console.WriteLine("{0}: Device {1} produced data at {2}.",
        DateTime.Now, device.Id, data.Created);

    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
}
```

it produces the following output:

```
30.4.2011 20:40:43: Device 1 produced data at 30.4.2011 20:40:43.
30.4.2011 20:40:45: Device 2 produced data at 30.4.2011 20:40:44.
30.4.2011 20:40:47: Device 1 produced data at 30.4.2011 20:40:47.
30.4.2011 20:40:49: Device 2 produced data at 30.4.2011 20:40:49.
30.4.2011 20:40:51: Device 1 produced data at 30.4.2011 20:40:51.
30.4.2011 20:40:54: Device 2 produced data at 30.4.2011 20:40:54.
```

Comment: Thanks, i think that should work for me! However I'm still investigating if i can implement what i want using standard collections, probably ConcurrentDictionary or using some "trick" suggested by Victor Hurdugaci. Your suggestion should work, but probably we can do the same easier...

Comment: after all I think i only want to store "index" of the updated sensor. Actual sensor data is stored in one place and I access it by reference. So I need no-duplicates ConcurentQueue where I will store "integers" - sensor indexes. created separate thread for my new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5845241/how-to-create-no-duplicates-concurrentqueue

Comment: Well, my solution does that. If you don't want to store any data for each device, you can use `HashSet<T>` instead of the `Dictionary`. Or you could check the `Queue` itself, but that would be slower (at least asymptotically, it may be fast enough for your needs).

Comment: This doesn't work, because `BlockingCollection` keeps count of added and taken items. And if you `update` instead of `add` an item, it breaks it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using another data structure, do another trick. The element in your collection cannot be replaced but you can, instead of storing the actual value, store a mini container. When you want to replace, you actually replace the value in the container, instead of replacing the container.

```
class ElementFromQueue
{
     public object SensorData;
}

...

ElementFromQueue elem = new ElementFromQueue();
elem.SensorData = new object();
...
queue.Add(elem); //Element is in queue now
...
elem.SensorData = new object(); //Update the data, simulating replace
```

Or just create a queue of indices that will point to a sensor number. When a value is popped, the latest sensor value is queried from another, update-able collection

Comment: if i create queue of indices, i need to have each index present one time, otherwise I can twice send the same sensor data. I.e. I need "set" of indixes :) But in general approach is intersting, I will try to apply it.